# Regular expression search and replace across whole directory in Linux terminal

Tags: regex, linux, terminal

In my PHP project, I have a PHP function that does some language stuff and is being called as:

```
<?php echo __('STRING'); ?>
```

I would like to switch from the consistent usage of uppercase string indexes, to a consistent usage of lowercase string indexes, so I would like to replace all these occurances:

```
__('SOMETHING')
```

With:

```
__('something')
```

What would be the command to do this?

I have a command ready for easy search & replace functionality, but I don't know how to write the regex.

```
find . -name "*.php" -print | xargs sed -i 's/search/replace/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-print0` with `xargs -0`:

```
find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sed -i.bak 's/search/replace/g' {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function.

Example:-

```
<?php
echo strtolower("Hello WORLD.");
?>
```

Result:-

```
hello world.
```